# Compare two vectors (including multiple items)

Tags: r

I need to find which elements in a new vector (vb) have been added to another vector (va). If there for example is unly one "2" in va, but two "2" in vb, then one "2" has been added.

The comment in the code below shows what is sought.

```
va <- c(1, 2)  # Original vector
vb <- c(1, 2)  # NA or NULL
vb <- c(2, 2)  # 2
vb <- c(1, 1)  # 1
vb <- c(1)     # NA or NULL
vb <- c(2)     # NA or NULL
vb <- c(3, 3)  # c(3, 3)
```

I've tried match, union, intersect, %in%, etc. but can't get it to work to consider also multiple instances. This feels irritatingly simple...

Comment: `vb[va != vb]` only fails in case 5. This is because `vb` is of length 1 and therefore `!=` recycles that value to the length of `va`, falling in case 2. Are you sure you want case 5 to return `NA` or `NULL`? If so, what would be the difference from case 2?

Comment: Thanks, but in case c(2, 2) there are two "2", i.e. one more than in va, so one was added. In case c(2), there is only one "2" so no more "2" than in va.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most elegant, but it works for all your cases:

```
Diff_frequency <- function(va,vb){
  df <- merge(as.data.frame(table(va)), as.data.frame(table(vb)), by.x="va", by.y="vb", all=T)
  df$Freq.x[is.na(df$Freq.x)] <- 0
  df$Dif <- df$Freq.y - df$Freq.x
  df$Dif[is.na(df$Dif) | df$Dif < 0] <- 0
  return(rep(as.numeric(as.character(df[,1])), df$Dif))
}

Diff_frequency(va,vb)
```

Examples of output:

```
va=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
vb=c(1,1,4,4,2,2,5)
Diff_frequency(va,vb)

[1] 4 4 5

va=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
vb=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,5)
Diff_frequency(va,vb)

1] 1 3 5

va=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)
vb=c(1,1,2,3)
Diff_frequency(va,vb)

numeric(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following reproduces your expected outcome. Just as an honest heads-up, I'm not really happy with my solution, this seems oddly convoluted:

```
f <- function(a, b) {
    a <- as.data.frame(unclass(rle(a)));
    b <- as.data.frame(unclass(rle(b)));
    t <- merge(a, b, by = "values", all = TRUE);
    t$lengths.x[is.na(t$lengths.x)] <- 0;
    t$diff <- t$lengths.y - t$lengths.x;
    t <- t[!is.na(t$diff) & t$diff > 0, ];
    return(rep(t$values, t$diff));
}

va <- c(1, 2);
vb <- c(1, 2)  # NA or NULL
f(va, vb);
#numeric(0)

vb <- c(2, 2)  # 2
f(va, vb);
#[1] 2

vb <- c(1, 1)  # 1
f(va, vb);
#[1] 1

vb <- c(1)     # NA or NULL
f(va, vb);
#numeric(0)

vb <- c(2)     # NA or NULL
f(va, vb);
#numeric(0)

vb <- c(3, 3)  # c(3, 3)
#[1] 3 3
```

Explanation: I'm making use of `rle` to compare the lengths (level of duplicity) of different entries in `va` and `vb`; then report only those that are not already in `va`.

---

### Update

Here is a much cleaner method using a recursive function.

```
f <- function(a, b) {
    if (length(a) == 0 | length(b) == 0) return(NULL);
    m <- data.frame(idx.a = 1:length(a), idx.b = match(a, b));
    m <- m[complete.cases(m), ];
    # Here is the recursive call
    if (nrow(m) > 0) f(a[-m$idx.a[1]], b[-m$idx.b[1]]) else b;
}

va <- c(1, 2)  # Original vector


f(va, c(1, 2));
#NULL

f(va, c(2, 2));
#[1] 2

f(va, c(1, 1));
#[1] 1

f(va, c(1));
#NULL

f(va, c(2));
#NULL

f(va, c(3, 3));
#[1] 3 3
```

Comment: Thanks. rle was new to me.

Comment: @Chris I've updated my answer to include a much cleaner solution using a recursive function. Please take a look.